# Ionic/AngularJS 2nd request not sending data but getting success answer

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I get the following issue when the user click the "login" button. Everything get well until the "addOrCreateUser" function. Here the POST request seems to be executed (I get an OK alert). Nevertheless, I have no log in my server side. I tried to lunch the "addOrCreateUser" based on a button click and then it works. Any idea?

```
.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http, $localStorage, $location) {


    $scope.form = {};


    $scope.login = function () {
      $cordovaOauth.facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxx", ["email"]).then(function (result) {

        $localStorage.accessToken = result.access_token;

        getUser($localStorage.accessToken);

      }, function (error) {
        alert("There was a problem signing in!  See the console for logs");
        console.log(error);
      })
    }



    function getUser(token) {

      $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me", {
        params: {
          access_token: token,
          fields: "id,email",
          format: "json"
        }

      }).then(function (result2) {

        $scope.form = {
          'id' : result2.data.id,
          'email' : result2.data.email
        }

        addOrCreateUser($localStorage.accessToken, $scope.form);

      }, function (error) {
        alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
        console.log(error);
      });
    }



    function addOrCreateUser (token, form) {

      $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = token;

      $http({
        url: API_URL + "/profiles",
        data: form,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("ok" + data )

      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("ko")
      });
    }
})
```

Comment: What are you getting back in you response (data, status, headers, config)?

Comment: data : "" 
status : 200
headers : function (name) {if(!headersObj=parseHeaders(headers)...}
config : [object;object]